# Probability and Transformation function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, binomial-distribution

Can anyone explain to me how to deal with this question? Many thanks

[image]

I tried the following steps:

As $P(Y \le y)=P(\psi(V) \le y)=P(V \le \psi^{-1}(y))=\psi^{-1}(y)=\begin{cases}
 1&\text{if}\, y\geq 1\\
 1-p&\text{if}\, 0\le y<1\\
      0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

but then I realised this is meaning less since $\psi^{-1}(y)$ is obviously not a one-to-one function and $\psi^(y)$ may not necessarily be a function. I really don't have a clue about how to move on. Please give me a hand!

Comment: Use the [generalized inverse CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Inverse_distribution_function_(quantile_function)).

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi$ is defined as
$$\phi(V)=\min\!\left(\left\lfloor{\frac{V}{1-p}}\right\rfloor,1\right)$$
then
$$
\phi(V)=
\begin{cases}
0\;\text{with probability}\;1-p\\[4pt]
1\;\text{with probability}\;p\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$
so $\phi(V)$ has the same distribution as $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

In general if $X$ is a random variable with CDF $\mathsf F$ and $V$ has uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ and we prescribe $\Phi_F:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ by:$$v\mapsto\inf\{y\in\mathbb R\mid\mathsf F(y)\geq v\}$$

then $\Phi_F(V)$ can be shown to have the same distribution as $X$.

This because: $$\Phi_F(v)\leq x\iff v\leq\mathsf F(x)$$so that $$\mathsf P(\Phi_F(V)\leq x)=\mathsf P(V\leq\mathsf F(x))=\mathsf F(x)$$

You can apply this here.